# Iphone/Ipad crashes when zooming

Tags: ios, css, iphone, safari, crash

Go to this page with an Iphone (safari): https://www.blush.no/k/kc.aspx?bn=15411 and then try to zoom all the way in to one of the buttons that says "Kjøp". If it does not crash the first time, try to zoom out and then in again. You will experence either:

1. The iphone is actually restarting
2. The page is reloaded with a message "A problem occured with this webpage so it was reloaded"

From my experience this is easiest reproduceable with Iphone 6+.

Something in the CSS triggers this, but i have no idea what.  If I remove all the CSS, the page does not crash, and also if I remove all CSS except bootstrap, it's working OK.

If i start to remove parts of the CSS, its getting better and crashes not so often, but I'm struggelig to pinpoint what exactly is going on.

Edit: Crash report:

```
"app_name":"com.apple.WebKit.WebContent","app_version":"8600","bundleID":"com.apple.WebKit.WebContent","os_version":"iPhone OS 8.1.2 (12B440)","slice_uuid":"879f2abd-e62f-367f-b1e6-9a6be7dc350d","share_with_app_devs":false,"build_version":"8600.1.4.12.4","is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","name":"com.apple.WebKit.WebContent"}
Incident Identifier: ABFAF96D-40DA-4493-9859-D8A2F0EAEAE7
CrashReporter Key:   8eb00d4acd97c6438f5fd670003d3722fcc59215
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,1
Process:             com.apple.WebKit.WebContent [411]
Path:                /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/XPCServices/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.xpc/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent
Identifier:          com.apple.WebKit.WebContent
Version:             8600.1.4.12.4 (8600)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-02-24 15:05:50.913 +0100
Launch Time:         2015-02-24 14:57:40.568 +0100
OS Version:          iOS 8.1.2 (12B440)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000001
Triggered by Thread:  5

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001949f4f60 0x1949f4000 + 3936
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194aac494 0x194aa8000 + 17556
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000184f8d510 0x184f80000 + 54544
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000184f82a3c 0x184f80000 + 10812
4   WebCore                         0x00000001920f5654 0x1914b0000 + 12867156
5   WebCore                         0x00000001920f4e80 0x1914b0000 + 12865152
6   WebCore                         0x00000001920f562c 0x1914b0000 + 12867116
7   WebCore                         0x00000001920f4e80 0x1914b0000 + 12865152
8   WebCore                         0x00000001920f562c 0x1914b0000 + 12867116
9   WebCore                         0x00000001920f4e80 0x1914b0000 + 12865152
10  WebCore                         0x00000001920f562c 0x1914b0000 + 12867116
11  WebCore                         0x00000001920f4e80 0x1914b0000 + 12865152
12  WebCore                         0x00000001920f562c 0x1914b0000 + 12867116
13  WebCore                         0x00000001920f4e80 0x1914b0000 + 12865152
14  WebCore                         0x00000001920f562c 0x1914b0000 + 12867116
15  WebCore                         0x00000001920f4e80 0x1914b0000 + 12865152
16  WebCore                         0x00000001920f562c 0x1914b0000 + 12867116
17  WebCore                         0x00000001920f4e80 0x1914b0000 + 12865152
18  WebCore                         0x00000001920f562c 0x1914b0000 + 12867116
19  WebCore                         0x00000001920f4e80 0x1914b0000 + 12865152
20  WebCore                         0x00000001920f562c 0x1914b0000 + 12867116
21  WebCore                         0x00000001920f4e80 0x1914b0000 + 12865152
22  WebCore                         0x00000001920f562c 0x1914b0000 + 12867116
23  WebCore                         0x00000001920f4e80 0x1914b0000 + 12865152
24  WebCore                         0x00000001920f562c 0x1914b0000 + 12867116
25  WebCore                         0x00000001920f4e80 0x1914b0000 + 12865152
26  WebCore                         0x00000001920f562c 0x1914b0000 + 12867116
27  WebCore                         0x00000001920f4e80 0x1914b0000 + 12865152
28  WebCore                         0x00000001920f562c 0x1914b0000 + 12867116
29  WebCore                         0x00000001920f4e80 0x1914b0000 + 12865152
30  WebCore                         0x00000001920f562c 0x1914b0000 + 12867116
31  WebCore                         0x00000001920f4e80 0x1914b0000 + 12865152
32  WebCore                         0x0000000191882d54 0x1914b0000 + 4009300
33  WebCore                         0x000000019159b7c4 0x1914b0000 + 964548
34  WebCore                         0x000000019162856c 0x1914b0000 + 1541484
35  WebCore                         0x0000000191628460 0x1914b0000 + 1541216
36  WebCore                         0x0000000191f242c4 0x1914b0000 + 10961604
37  WebCore                         0x0000000191eed920 0x1914b0000 + 10737952
38  WebCore                         0x0000000191eed5e4 0x1914b0000 + 10737124
39  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001948cd368 0x1948cc000 + 4968
40  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001948e20c4 0x1948cc000 + 90308
41  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001948cf4d0 0x1948cc000 + 13520
42  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001948d1780 0x1948cc000 + 22400
43  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183ae1fa0 0x183a04000 + 909216
44  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183ae0048 0x183a04000 + 901192
45  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183a0d0a0 0x183a04000 + 37024
46  Foundation                      0x0000000184915800 0x184908000 + 55296
47  Foundation                      0x000000018496fef4 0x184908000 + 425716
48  libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000194adc22c 0x194acc000 + 66092
49  libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000194addf50 0x194acc000 + 73552
50  com.apple.WebKit.WebContent     0x000000010004fa7c 0x10004c000 + 14972
51  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001948f6a04 0x1948f4000 + 10756

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001949f4c94 0x1949f4000 + 3220
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001948dc97c 0x1948cc000 + 67964
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001948cf3b0 0x1948cc000 + 13232

Thread 2 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194a0f078 0x1949f4000 + 110712
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194aaafe0 0x194aa8000 + 12256
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000193a08cac 0x193a00000 + 36012
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000184f995f8 0x184f80000 + 103928
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000184f94b7c 0x184f80000 + 84860
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194aabe7c 0x194aa8000 + 15996
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194aabdd8 0x194aa8000 + 15832
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194aa8fac 0x194aa8000 + 4012

Thread 3 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194a0f078 0x1949f4000 + 110712
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194aaafe0 0x194aa8000 + 12256
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000193a08cac 0x193a00000 + 36012
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001852428b8 0x184f80000 + 2894008
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018524295c 0x184f80000 + 2894172
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000184f94b7c 0x184f80000 + 84860
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194aabe7c 0x194aa8000 + 15996
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194aabdd8 0x194aa8000 + 15832
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194aa8fac 0x194aa8000 + 4012

Thread 4 name:  DFG Worklist Worker Thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194a0f078 0x1949f4000 + 110712
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194aaafe0 0x194aa8000 + 12256
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001851f5480 0x184f80000 + 2577536
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000184f94b7c 0x184f80000 + 84860
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194aabe7c 0x194aa8000 + 15996
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194aabdd8 0x194aa8000 + 15832
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194aa8fac 0x194aa8000 + 4012

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: CA::CG::Queue
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib      0x000000018c4ce128 0x18c4cc000 + 8488
1   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib      0x000000018c4cf124 0x18c4cc000 + 12580
2   QuartzCore                      0x0000000187c4fb00 0x187c24000 + 178944
3   QuartzCore                      0x0000000187c4f50c 0x187c24000 + 177420
4   QuartzCore                      0x0000000187c50ac4 0x187c24000 + 182980
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001948cd368 0x1948cc000 + 4968
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001948d6468 0x1948cc000 + 42088
7   QuartzCore                      0x0000000187d29220 0x187c24000 + 1069600
8   WebKit                          0x0000000188d82d84 0x188cc0000 + 798084
9   WebKit                          0x0000000188d82b70 0x188cc0000 + 797552
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001948cd3a8 0x1948cc000 + 5032
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001948cd368 0x1948cc000 + 4968
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001948d74bc 0x1948cc000 + 46268
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001948d0470 0x1948cc000 + 17520
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001948d9220 0x1948cc000 + 53792
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001948da758 0x1948cc000 + 59224
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194aa92e0 0x194aa8000 + 4832
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194aa8fa4 0x194aa8000 + 4004

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194a0fc78 0x1949f4000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194aa9390 0x194aa8000 + 5008
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194aa8fa4 0x194aa8000 + 4004

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194a0fc78 0x1949f4000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194aa9390 0x194aa8000 + 5008
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194aa8fa4 0x194aa8000 + 4004

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194a0fc78 0x1949f4000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194aa9390 0x194aa8000 + 5008
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194aa8fa4 0x194aa8000 + 4004

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194a0fc78 0x1949f4000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194aa9390 0x194aa8000 + 5008
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194aa8fa4 0x194aa8000 + 4004

Thread 5 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000145900040   x1: 0x0000000080000000   x2: 0x00000000ffffffff   x3: 0x000000000000002e
    x4: 0x00000001446f0d00   x5: 0x0000000000000020   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000000000001   x9: 0x00000000deadbeef  x10: 0x0000000147950000  x11: 0x0000000000000fff
   x12: 0x000000000000002e  x13: 0x000000014794c000  x14: 0x0000000000003fff  x15: 0x0000000000003fff
   x16: 0x000000018c4ce1b4  x17: 0x00000000000004c4  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000146800000
   x20: 0x0000000000000000  x21: 0x000000014680085c  x22: 0x000000010348c0e0  x23: 0x0000000144629c10
   x24: 0x0000000144557a50  x25: 0x00000000a40008ff  x26: 0x0000000000010001  x27: 0x000000019857e0c0
   x28: 0x0000000000000000  fp: 0x000000010348bb40   lr: 0x000000018c4cf128
    sp: 0x000000010348baf0   pc: 0x000000018c4ce128 cpsr: 0x60000000

Binary Images:
0x10004c000 - 0x10004ffff com.apple.WebKit.WebContent arm64  <879f2abde62f367fb1e69a6be7dc350d> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/XPCServices/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.xpc/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent
0x101c70000 - 0x101c8ffff Safari arm64  <25120c3675d13f5ba39ae740842f1422> /Applications/MobileSafari.app/Safari.wkbundle/Safari
0x120068000 - 0x12008ffff dyld arm64  <36eff49275c23d2d815e48af33eea471> /usr/lib/dyld
0x181ff8000 - 0x181ff8fff WebProcessLoader arm64  <ba230f42e73239d9bda0122d51f95f77> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/WebProcessLoader.axbundle/WebProcessLoader
0x18213c000 - 0x182236fff RawCamera arm64  <6bbc4b9acb833146b6474984ffb64519> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x182254000 - 0x1822ebfff AGXGLDriver arm64  <588a1155fa4131eb8bf4d6e61d7fa98b> /System/Library/Extensions/AGXGLDriver.bundle/AGXGLDriver
0x182304000 - 0x182497fff AVFoundation arm64  <c9cd60a62cfb3e77be72db6cd3062a09> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x182498000 - 0x1824fcfff libAVFAudio.dylib arm64  <017d90360b443ae788ef31cfd73d17f6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
0x182540000 - 0x182540fff Accelerate arm64  <e9ba7838f51634a7b59ed392be50e86f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x182558000 - 0x182777fff vImage arm64  <da44067fc79931c7aef1b7e88bf82a83> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x182778000 - 0x18281ffff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <e5276e7784ef34a4baca480264978ea0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x182820000 - 0x182b9afff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <165b05f9f75736d5ae8f5f39293bd6e7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x182b9c000 - 0x182bb1fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <5574ec3bd4e537e1b662d38a63aec58b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x182bb4000 - 0x182c1cfff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <004f5668574139bc906c5fa4fdced3b1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x182c20000 - 0x182c43fff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <5790e7ace143367ea6f2428852be384e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x182c44000 - 0x182c44fff vecLib arm64  <211d7711a6e93fe8ae6d6b42585cad2d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x182c48000 - 0x182c76fff Accounts arm64  <2508d336b9893176ad4e1bc67ff04188> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x182c7c000 - 0x182cfefff AddressBook arm64  <09e2e24ef5e23fb8a62ae209466a64bd> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x183018000 - 0x1832d5fff AudioToolbox arm64  <f0b739a395993b808d66e85e1a6e9f18> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x183474000 - 0x18367ffff CFNetwork arm64  <68adcebf440d30769bd2d67adc7932a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x183680000 - 0x183717fff CloudKit arm64  <8f226c83b2793a0db1eefa14d697c04b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CloudKit.framework/CloudKit
0x183718000 - 0x18377dfff CoreAudio arm64  <10aae62ba1c43dd29bc678fbf0f985ef> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x1837a0000 - 0x1837c1fff CoreBluetooth arm64  <9ccc8812db60356ebb123ca9ca36f958> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x1837c4000 - 0x183a02fff CoreData arm64  <33c0d795a45e35c9affed5cf9d83a8a1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x183a04000 - 0x183d60fff CoreFoundation arm64  <83a9627362333366a8543e8c2d28166e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x183d64000 - 0x183ec6fff CoreGraphics arm64  <783a6b9356ed3b41beba516b483affb1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x183f1c000 - 0x183f1efff libCGXType.A.dylib arm64  <a23bc017fe0d3c2293a1391fe5ef658b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
0x183f20000 - 0x183f2bfff libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib arm64  <f691d5f2368d3b7d8668c7cbf6044af7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib
0x1840fc000 - 0x18411cfff libPDFRIP.A.dylib arm64  <27d25b7232dc33d682eb3bd758411343> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libPDFRIP.A.dylib
0x184120000 - 0x18413efff libRIP.A.dylib arm64  <c7960ba6e4183d9cbb673b112b6ba300> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x184140000 - 0x18426dfff CoreImage arm64  <444c44b06f533bad9c1b030edd486b49> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x184270000 - 0x1842cdfff CoreLocation arm64  <d8470e5719473c82a5f089624a04a1e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x184308000 - 0x1843c6fff CoreMedia arm64  <af73ae8152763066a3fc18bcbcdecf94> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x1843c8000 - 0x184496fff CoreMotion arm64  <b4148dfdca2036e893becf42286d9e09> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x184498000 - 0x184509fff CoreTelephony arm64  <f99cf601387938d3808c32e97a9a30cf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x18450c000 - 0x18460efff CoreText arm64  <128434ae7dda35bf8830f1914999fe3a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x184610000 - 0x18462cfff CoreVideo arm64  <402f868dbba63d59a3b2e738982b9d71> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x184908000 - 0x184b5cfff Foundation arm64  <fb0544132648377c8d2683d597a3583d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x184c74000 - 0x184ce0fff IOKit arm64  <1cd3da5151d03be5a0ba0c30c19228ea> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x184ce4000 - 0x184f7efff ImageIO arm64  <100a3b5e1ea13c89a9771cad8f9508b2> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x184f80000 - 0x185420fff JavaScriptCore arm64  <8b0fade3317b38358fe56ac5ba61e2f3> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x185c94000 - 0x185c9afff MediaAccessibility arm64  <5dc0d8bda3593b9cb00a8703b21953fd> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x185c9c000 - 0x185eb7fff MediaPlayer arm64  <5c56df4977f33b41bdc6b6aed053f85b> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x185eb8000 - 0x1862d2fff MediaToolbox arm64  <0468767c75bb342cbbefc64bdf948be5> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x1863a8000 - 0x18641bfff Metal arm64  <69e3d92ae3ec3375a550022b7ac4a184> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x18641c000 - 0x1864c8fff MobileCoreServices arm64  <19505cbb66af328785e293c3b2810b00> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x18652c000 - 0x1865d7fff NetworkExtension arm64  <f6cf2251d47c3f2aa1abe6b494e67a58> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetworkExtension.framework/NetworkExtension
0x187554000 - 0x187648fff GLEngine arm64  <f1c267a97d25316aa06e261d0a7a6f93> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
0x18764c000 - 0x187656fff OpenGLES arm64  <b707e102e4553f26994bfef0579c9f52> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x18765c000 - 0x18765dfff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64  <7e1f08d7776b37efb6ff01f6486afcde> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x187660000 - 0x187663fff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64  <5888d3587c633af2ac7cf57ac15ab5e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x187664000 - 0x187668fff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64  <291806c545fe3219b844a93e2fb682b4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x18766c000 - 0x187676fff libGFXShared.dylib arm64  <f5e5cfc1d6673d469f25b3fa77fa995b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x187678000 - 0x1876c3fff libGLImage.dylib arm64  <4e284cf07fe23789b94c9f204f7aa52e> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x1876c4000 - 0x18783ffff libGLProgrammability.dylib arm64  <2e066dab395a305b9409b418f5dbcec0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x187c24000 - 0x187da8fff QuartzCore arm64  <313aba56d17e30d1b68b2fdfda1820f8> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x187dac000 - 0x187e07fff QuickLook arm64  <ae12a3ed0acf3b6ca816e95d4a894d70> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x18803c000 - 0x18808efff Security arm64  <823c0a3088543396bef1e351da74c835> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x188254000 - 0x1882c7fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <cbcb5237ab8637aebf0cb493aaa4af92> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x1882cc000 - 0x188c40fff UIKit arm64  <31ac3f3fa5153620907fbfbfd1d671b0> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x188c44000 - 0x188cbdfff VideoToolbox arm64  <13a05b41cd0136239ef94de508febe1d> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x188cc0000 - 0x188f21fff WebKit arm64  <ec363b6f17ba3f068df0b771aa8ddc44> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x1892c4000 - 0x1892c7fff AGXCompilerConnection arm64  <dca7ebb27c1735c299a4ec26e1529213> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AGXCompilerConnection.framework/AGXCompilerConnection
0x189568000 - 0x18956dfff AggregateDictionary arm64  <2f9120e6400835f08bd7bfd2d4ada020> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x18976c000 - 0x1897a0fff AirPlaySupport arm64  <6f3dd0a70c643317b21ca301bd142257> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirPlaySupport.framework/AirPlaySupport
0x1899ec000 - 0x189a36fff AppSupport arm64  <f35ee13bec64354d9044e2a5ea519640> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x189b94000 - 0x189bdcfff AppleJPEG arm64  <8377453201ad3862b7b6182be4ac4342> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x189bf0000 - 0x189c04fff ApplePushService arm64  <fc28105486c5380f95f8d52a3a3c2fac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x189c08000 - 0x189c11fff AppleSRP arm64  <7a5d169c15b83573a29f1c018c8ecbb8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSRP.framework/AppleSRP
0x189c24000 - 0x189c2ffff AssertionServices arm64  <52d911832bf9382d802961ea9d1614f9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x189c30000 - 0x189c4bfff AssetsLibraryServices arm64  <5db6341939f63eaa86f0c0306e2b59c9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x189cb0000 - 0x189cb4fff BTLEAudioController arm64  <8539b6078e1b3c739d412842418188ed> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BTLEAudioController.framework/BTLEAudioController
0x189cb8000 - 0x189cd4fff BackBoardServices arm64  <6ff3989d8caf3130aa41d0019ead5472> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x189cdc000 - 0x189d19fff BaseBoard arm64  <62044bafc2293567aec7797b25708b48> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x189d34000 - 0x189d3bfff BluetoothManager arm64  <2b1c765aab5a3ba6b6f8ded22ce99d6b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager
0x189fcc000 - 0x189fd6fff CaptiveNetwork arm64  <8ba9d547383b3a7fba9a31cc361fc06a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x189fd8000 - 0x18a122fff Celestial arm64  <24aa1094177c3a5ead8cd4fa3369b83a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x18a150000 - 0x18a156fff CertUI arm64  <d540e6a6a1ab3b119b88d31509a2f390> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x18a2a0000 - 0x18a2c4fff ChunkingLibrary arm64  <ef3f4a4cae2d387b874e53eec51b37aa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/ChunkingLibrary
0x18a2c8000 - 0x18a308fff CloudDocs arm64  <64909a1b4c5b33c6969a03810c2b6000> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudDocs.framework/CloudDocs
0x18a7cc000 - 0x18a81afff ColorSync arm64  <612acd6af4323adbb30db1157bd6afd2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ColorSync.framework/ColorSync
0x18a820000 - 0x18a832fff CommonUtilities arm64  <1cb495ce473a3127bb291cc541762fb3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x18a834000 - 0x18a838fff CommunicationsFilter arm64  <836ffdf2d1bf38948dc8ce6c2f8179e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommunicationsFilter.framework/CommunicationsFilter
0x18a8c0000 - 0x18a8c5fff ConstantClasses arm64  <855d1ee3980637a1b48a47adf5327c35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConstantClasses.framework/ConstantClasses
0x18a908000 - 0x18a90cfff CoreAUC arm64  <bf359bb9dcc837f78745ec21c2983ad2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAUC.framework/CoreAUC
0x18a9a4000 - 0x18a9c3fff CoreDuet arm64  <f38d1f4e98f53778b1b9a404036dd90d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuet.framework/CoreDuet
0x18a9c8000 - 0x18a9dafff CoreDuetDaemonProtocol arm64  <d7407f2a063d39139970e64968ff7b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol.framework/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol
0x18a9e4000 - 0x18a9e6fff CoreDuetDebugLogging arm64  <c794669b592d361d850e98c474076c01> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDebugLogging.framework/CoreDuetDebugLogging
0x18aca4000 - 0x18ad54fff CorePDF arm64  <cd828d67cd5a3f8f817e5578de264442> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CorePDF.framework/CorePDF
0x18b0e8000 - 0x18b17afff CoreUI arm64  <2c327f9d33a0390a9e4eca6c3762e371> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI
0x18b17c000 - 0x18b1f8fff CoreUtils arm64  <b41c5bba90743d249a117bfcfb49d2cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUtils.framework/CoreUtils
0x18b1fc000 - 0x18b202fff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <dc54f922fd9636bcb707444caca99c84> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x18b204000 - 0x18b20bfff DAAPKit arm64  <b631761d5d3c34e1a12ea2f07efa9055> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DAAPKit.framework/DAAPKit
0x18b4c4000 - 0x18b4eafff DataAccessExpress arm64  <50d5ab9c38ee3e69bd4da116bc7bd4f8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x18b4f8000 - 0x18b514fff DataDetectorsCore arm64  <24f23c8aff76314d8ad25a94fa4705cf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x18b518000 - 0x18b518fff PhoneNumbers arm64  <22c29728209532689c3c56e7fd216b59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/PlugIns/PhoneNumbers.plugin/PhoneNumbers
0x18b53c000 - 0x18b543fff DataMigration arm64  <e0c839ae4aed387887ea9853c6c25682> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x18b54c000 - 0x18b54dfff DiagnosticLogCollection arm64  <fa41e1d5be703f8e80e8ff3316a49e3d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiagnosticLogCollection.framework/DiagnosticLogCollection
0x18b550000 - 0x18b570fff DictionaryServices arm64  <d4d267ee319135ccb3a6679497243088> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x18b598000 - 0x18b5befff EAP8021X arm64  <e6e05a22dbb1320690b65f4eb029d79e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x18b720000 - 0x18bb4dfff FaceCore arm64  <a0f71a06ddb83c77b3b59257e4002445> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
0x18bb80000 - 0x18bb80fff FontServices arm64  <ee0991095b7e3183b4776c88a2f611e3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/FontServices
0x18bb84000 - 0x18bc63fff libFontParser.dylib arm64  <9002a342951f3cc98421946872538a41> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libFontParser.dylib
0x18bc64000 - 0x18bc70fff libGSFontCache.dylib arm64  <0c92c17ccfd03da88fd356e758e17497> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libGSFontCache.dylib
0x18bd80000 - 0x18bda0fff FrontBoardServices arm64  <0fcec11d993d3b30a5ef89f6bf0ad46a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
```

Full report here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=hUb1GHJ6

Does anyone have any clue of what might be wrong?

Comment: This may or may not be related, but I've encountered quite a few bugs with safari and embedded web view controllers. In my experience, certain CSS or Javascript on pages aren't handled properly, and will crash when zooming OR rotating in webviews as well as safari.

Comment: Can this be recreated anywhere in a PC bowser or is this just iPhone/iPad Safari related? Also why not just not allow zoom? The page doesn't give you a lot from using the zoom feature. The page is clear enough without it.

Comment: I disagree with you @ruddy. The page is not yet optimized for mobile and therefore, disallow zooming makes the user experience on mobile even worse. This is only a problem om Iphone devices and especally iphone 6+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were doing a lot of debugging, and we finally found a solution. We have a "skip navigation" link which is only showing when you press "tab" on your keyboard. This was initially set to "text-indent: -10000px". This probably causes the viewport to be over 10000 px in width and then causes the phone to use too much memory and then eventually crashes. We have fixed this by removing this css rule, so blush.no does not crash that much anymore.

Iphone still have a problem with memory leakage, and until they fix this, the site will sometimes crash, but not as near as much as it did before.

Answer (score 2):

I found this question while having a similar problem with a site using Bootstrap 3.3.2. Since this question is a popular result when researching "ipad zoom crash" issues, I thought I'd add my findings here.

The page I was having issues with was image heavy, and crashed every time I tried to zoom in using any iOS device running below iOS 8 using Safari.

In my case the problem was caused by the `.table-responsive` class, which sets a `min-height` of `0.01%`. Once removed, zooming on the page worked fine.

When debugging issues like this, I feel the best approach is to remove as much content as you can from the page and then add it back one piece at a time until you find out what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is full of many bloated and un-necessary things.  Try 2 things.   Remove the CSS classes from those pink buttons.  Also try adding the below meta tag to the page.  Either of those 2 should fix the issue, let me know if it does not.

Remove the classes from the buttons:

```
button-buy-small button button-primary button-small gradient
```

Try adding this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
```

Comment: I have removed bootstrap completely, but it still hangs so this bug is unreleated to bootstrap, but I will try what you suggest :)

Comment: adding the meta view port removes the ability for the site to be "zoomable" on ios devices.  Let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: Disallowing zooming is not an option

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and what was causing it was `transform: transalteZ(0)` which I was applying to solve the issue with blurred images in Chrome.

Answer (score -2):

If this site of yours is responsive, which implies that the navigation experience doesn't include any zoom from the user, you probably want to insert this tag in your head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
```

This will prevent the page from zooming.

Comment: Disallowing zooming is not an option